# Implementing queues using SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, message-queue, database-performance

I want to implement queues in one of my app. I've been investigating few options like file based queues and database queues. File based doesn't look like a right choice when data grows really big. I'm more inclined towards SQLite based queues now since it can support the large data set. Wondering if someone has already implemented queues in android and the approaches taken. What is the best way to implement queues in a multithreaded environment in android?

[EDIT]
I want to make a queue for messages, which can grow really big if device is offline for long time and unable to flush queues to server. I feel SQLite could be better solution, but afraid if all the database loads as a first thing into memory when an app starts. I want to support really huge backlogs queues, but don't want to consume too much memory to load them all at once.

Answer (score 3):

> Wondering if someone has already implemented queues in android and the approaches taken

Square released [Tape](http://square.github.io/tape/), a persistent queue implementation for Android, that they use in their apps.

> File based doesn't look like a right choice when data grows really big.

IMHO, a persistent queue should never "grow really big". If the data associated with the queue entry is large, that suggests that some of that data should not be considered part of the queue data model, but part of the app's overall data model, resident elsewhere (e.g., SQLite) and be *pointed to* from the queue.

For example, suppose the queue is for image uploads. IMHO, those images are not part of the queue. The queue represents commands to upload images. The queue entries should point to where the images are stored, as those images likely serve other roles (e.g., cache entries) beyond simply waiting to be uploaded.

Comment: I've added my scenario in edit. please check. actually i want to support big queues, but don't want to slow down the system during backlog processing.

Comment: Your answer is great from designing the better queue perspective. I can understand large queues are not good, but still I've to support them. I'm more concerned about how a large SQLite database play with in an APP. What tools can I use to profile the memory usage and APP behavior when using Sqllite. Is there any better storage solution available in android, which is fast, responsive and load data as needed rather bringing everything at once.